# Why is $\mathrm{d} \Omega = \mathrm{d} \cos \theta \mathrm{d} \phi$ and not $\mathrm{d} \Omega = -\mathrm{d} \cos \theta \mathrm{d} \phi$?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, conventions, calculus, volume

The textbook I am following (Peskin&Schroeder) on QFT takes $\mathrm{d} \Omega = \mathrm{d} \cos \theta \mathrm{d} \phi$. I cannot for the life of me see that its correct. We know that $\mathrm{d}V = r^2 \sin \theta \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d} \theta \mathrm{d} \phi$. But $\mathrm{d} \cos \theta = - \sin \theta \mathrm{d} \theta$, so $\mathrm{d}V = -r^2 \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d} \phi \mathrm{d}\cos \theta $ only if $\mathrm{d} \Omega = -\mathrm{d}\cos \theta \mathrm{d} \phi$.

Can you see what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure they're not just throwing out the sign? When you're calculating cross sections you only ever care about solid angle, not signed solid angle.

Comment: No, I dont know. Peskin doesn't explain, he just writes up the answer.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which page?

Comment: For example pages 107 and 163.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you integrate $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$, but $\cos \theta$ from $-1$ to $1$ (P&S don't write the integration boundaries explicitly).

$$ \int_0^\pi \mathrm \sin\theta\, d\theta = \int_1^{-1} \mathrm d(-\cos\theta) = \int_{-1}^1 \mathrm d(\cos\theta) .$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the book at hand right now but my guess is that it is a case of

$$\int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta =\int_{-1}^1 d\cos\theta$$